# How to get the name of the seas, oceans and lakes and other reservoirs by coordinates?

Tags: python, geocoding

I have the breadth and longitude of the sea/ocean and the lake and other water space, I want to get its name, for example: -2.400116, -8.739542 -the southern part of the Atlantic Ocean.

Exmple, google returns me a certain code, request:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=2.400116.-8.739542&type=natural_Feature&key=
```

Response:

```
{
    "Plus_code": {
       "Global_code": "6c9hh7x6+X54"
    },
    "Results": [],
    "Status": "zero_results"
}
```

But how I could not figure it out for it to get the name